# Linting a TypeScript project with multiple entry points

Tags: typescript

I have a large application build using webpack to build it. The application has multiple (actually dynamically generated) entry points and generates a the needed target files for each entry point.

I already discovered that ts-loader should be used with the transpileOnly option when building but I'm stuck on how now to use tsc to check for (type) errors.

The most intuitive way of just invoking `tsc --noEmit ./**/*.ts` after invoking `tslint --config tslint.json ./**/*.ts` in my npm lint script but this does not work because tsc does not seem to allow any wildcards. I'm sure there is a simple and obvious solution but I cannot seem to find it.

Comment: Have you looked at using fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin? https://github.com/Realytics/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin#readme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `ts-loader` for transpilation, you can tell TypeScript not to emit code in `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noEmit": true,
    /* ... */
  },
  "include": [
    "your-source-directory"
  ]
}
```

Then your npm script can be reduced to just running `tsc`.

```
"scripts": {
  "type-check": "tsc"
}
```